# Single quotation inside string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-like

I have the following SQL query for searching purposes.

There is a `@st` variable and it is assigned a SQL query and at the end I will execute the query. The problem is the `@st` variable is assigned a string (which is query) and inside the string there is `LIKE` expression such as:

```
address like '%edmon%'
```

so it becomes:

```
set @st='select * from infoone where address like '%edmon%''
```

And it's causing an error:

> incorrect syntax near edmon

The full query is following,

```
declare @v int;
declare @st varchar(1000);

set @st = 'select PLACEID, LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(1000), description), 500) as
des1, LOCATIONCITY, ADDRESS, DateT, RENT from infoone where '; 

Select @v = count(address) 
from infoone  
where ((address like '%main%') OR (address like '%main street%') 
       OR (address like '%main street edmonton%'));

if @v>0 
begin 
    set @st = @st + '(address like '%main%') OR 
                     (address like '%main street%') OR 
                     (address like '%main street edmonton%')' + 
                    'and ('; 
end 
else begin
    execute(@st)
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and how to resolve it

Thanks

Comment: Anything that matches `LIKE '%main%'` is also going to match `LIKE '%main street%'` and `LIKE '%main street edmonton%'` - so why not just say `LIKE '%main%'`?

Comment: Also, getting a count is a terrible idea - it means SQL Server will literally have to count all of the rows that match. Since you only care if there is at least one row, use EXISTS like in M.Ali's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a single quote on a string, use `''`:

```
set @st = 'select * from infoone where address like ''%edmon%'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff has explained you where you are going wrong with your single quotes `'` but there are some other issues as well with your statement. a much better way of doing what you are trying to do would be something like this...

```
declare @st nvarchar(MAX);

set @st=N' select PLACEID
                ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(500),[description]) as des1
                ,LOCATIONCITY
                ,[ADDRESS]
                ,DateT
                ,RENT 
         from infoone  where 1 = 1 '; 

IF EXISTS (Select * from infoone  
                where(([ADDRESS] like '%main%') 
                   OR ([ADDRESS] like '%main street%') 
                   OR ([ADDRESS] like '%main street edmonton%')))
 begin 
   set @st = @st+ N' AND (
                       ([ADDRESS] like ''%main%'') 
                       OR
                       ([ADDRESS] like ''%main street%'') 
                       OR
                       ([ADDRESS] like ''%main street edmonton%'')
                      )'; 
 end 
else 
  begin
    set @st = @st+ N' AND  (Some Other Condition) )'
  end

EXECUTE sp_executesql @st
```

Comment: I agree that EXISTS is better than COUNT, but I don't really feel like this step is necessary. In fact it seems kind of confusing - if there is an address containing main in the table, then add this where clause and limit it to those rows, otherwise return everything? Also the three ORs are redundant. If anything matches %main% they're also going to match %main street% and %main street edmonton%.